# Short deadlines for a very good graduate program in Switzerland

Tags: student-visa, indian-citizens, switzerland

I really want to apply to a graduate program in Switzerland (applications open now) who will provide a decision by the end of June. In the event that I do get selected, classes start on September 15 or so. I just saw that the processing time for Indian students can take anywhere from 8-12 weeks. On top of that, apparently getting loan for study after being accepted also might take a substantial amount of time. Considering all this, there are two possibilities:

1. I might not make it in time.
2. Somehow, the process takes lesser than usual time.

Clearly, 1 is more likely. I want to know if it is possible if universities can somehow help in processing the visas faster, or if the visa processing people would be willing to speed up the process for a case such as mine.

Also, do universities reject desirable candidates just based on how long it will potentially take them to reach their country?

Comment: The last question: no. Where are plenty of PhD students from around the world (China has many of them), and it is not supposed that you travel every day or every week to your home country (and also Swiss students may travel on holidays on other continents), and that question is more suited for academia SE. University cannot help on visa (but on providing you good documentation). Just have plan B and plan C ready. Start collecting documents earlier, and prepare the application earlier (so you do not make the common last-minute errors which delay everything).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I understand. Thanks for your response.